# Javassist - Numeric operations in CtMethod method body throws java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: java, dynamic, classloader, java-assist

Please see below code of creating a class and method using javassist:

```
public Class generateClass(String className, String methodName)
            throws CannotCompileException, NotFoundException {
   ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
   CtClass cc = pool.makeClass(className);

   ClassLoader classLoader = FormulaAPI.class.getClassLoader();
   pool.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(classLoader));
   pool.importPackage("com.formula");

   String methodBody = "return ($w)($1.evaluate(\"L\") + 25.0);";

   CtClass apiClass = pool.get("com.formula.FormulaAPI");

   CtClass doubleWrapperClass = pool.get("java.lang.Double");

   CtMethod m = new CtMethod(doubleWrapperClass,methodName,new CtClass[]{apiClass},cc);
   m.setBody(methodBody);
   cc.addMethod(m);

   return cc.toClass();
}
```

After calling this method, I get the error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: Formulae, method: formula1 signature: (Lcom/formulabuilder/FormulaAPI;)Ljava/lang/Double;) Wrong return type in function**

Does Javassist not support numeric operations in method body? I am trying to call a method and add a number to it before it returns the value as below:

```
String methodBody = "return ($w)($1.evaluate(\"L\") + 25.0);";
```

How can I achieve numeric operations like +, *, /, <, <= etc. in method body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that javassist doesnt support autoboxing. So `java.lang.Double` is not compatible with `double`. Numeric operators are only available for primitive types.

So if you want to keep the signatures, you need to box/unbox the objects/primitives yourself.

Something like

```
String methodBody = "return java.lang.Double.valueOf($1.evaluate(\"L\").doubleValue() + 25.0d);";
```

(you might want to add `null` handling if `evaluate()` can return `null`)

Comment: Thank you for the solution!!